# closedness a subset of a Hilbert space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space that admits a countable orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}$. I know this means that $H$ is separable and so is $S$ (as a subset of it, defined below). Show that $S$ is a closed subset of $H$, where 
$$
S=\left\{\frac{i+1}{i} e_i \, :\,  i\geq 1\right\}.
$$
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** define $x_i:=\frac{i+1}ie_i$· Since $\lVert x_i-x_j\rVert_H\geqslant\sqrt 2$ if $i\neq j$, we can show sequential closeness.

Comment: Thanks. It is a good idea. This inequality shows that the sequence xn is not a Cauchy sequence unless it is a constant sequence  for n>= n0 for some n0. (i.e., after finitely many terms the sequence must be constant).

Comment: @Hamid Why is $x_n$ necessarily a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: Take x in cl(S). Then there exists a sequence (xn) in S such that (xn) converges to x( x is in X). Since (xn) is a convergent sequence (in X), then it is a Cauchy sequence. While any non-constant sequence in S is not Cauchy( because of the above inequality). This shows that (xn) must be a constant sequence and implies that x is in S. This proves the closedness of S.